# Elastic search alphabetical sorting based on first character

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have a collection of first names.

```
team dhoni
dhoni1
dibeesh 200
bb vineesh
devan
```

I want to sort it alphabetically ascending order (A - Z) like the following order

```
bb vineesh
devan
dhoni1
dibeesh 200
team dhoni
```

Mapping

```
 "first_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": "true"
},
```

I have tried

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "first_name": {
        "order": "asc"

      }
    }
  ], 
 "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  }
}
```

When i run this query am getting the names in following order.

```
dibeesh 200
bb vineesh
devan
team dhoni
dhoni1
```

Elastic search taking first names with number as first preference.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and the other answer didn't quite get it for me.  I referred to [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html) instead, and was able to solve by mapping like this

```
"name": { 
    "type":     "string",
    "analyzer": "english",
    "fields": {
        "raw": { 
            "type":  "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

and then querying and sorting like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "dhoni"
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "name.raw": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think problem is that, your string is analyzed on writing to elasticsearch. It use [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), An analyzer of type standard is built using the Standard Tokenizer with the Standard Token Filter, Lower Case Token Filter, and Stop Token Filter.

What does this mean, 
suppose you are using a field "name", with default mapping (standard analyzer).

when you index,

```
team dhoni, --> team, dhoni

dhoni1 --> dhoni1

dibeesh 200 --> dibeesh, 200
```

and so on,

so, by sorting it is obvious that dibeesh200 will come first. (because it will sort by 200 not dibesh)

So, If your string is not analyzed (upper case and lower case acts differently) or you may use simple analyzer (so that you can sort by letters only and doesn't matter upper case or lower) , or maybe you can use multifield to have analyzed and non_analyzed version.

Here is a way to do that,

```
POST x2/x3/_mapping
{
    "x3":{
        "properties": {
            "name" :{
                "type" :"string",
                "fields" :{
                    "raw" :{
                        "type": "string",
                        "index_analyzer": "simple"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the query,

```
POST x2/x3/_search
{
    "sort": [
       {
          "name.raw": {
             "order": "asc"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

This works as expected. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think my name field have analyzed mapping. I have a doubt you have given a mapping query, can i do it run time? How to execute both mapping and query together.

Comment: Runtime? using what? Just do the curl request seperately or run in sense

Comment: I have a mapping  
"first_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": "true"
}
what will happen when i run the first curl script. Is it change my mapping?

Comment: You delete and rerun the mapping.

Comment: I have already set some mapping for all the fields. I am not sure this will effect my mapping or not?

Comment: Yes, You have to somehow create a fresh type (with new mapping), and copy the data there.

Comment: @progrrammer I do it, but it dont work.. This form working split the name like "team dhoni, --> team, dhoni
dhoni1 --> dhoni1
dibeesh 200 --> dibeesh, 200"... Any other suggestion?

Comment: @progrrammer you mentioned "so, by sorting it is obvious that dibeesh200 will come first. (because it will sort by 200 not dibesh)" Can I know why standard analysers sort number before text and simple analysers sort text before number

Answer (score 4):

I am using ElasticSearch 6.3 (latest at this time)

and as per documents., for text sorting you need to set type as `keyword`.

```
"title":{ 
    "type":     "text",
    "fields": {
        "raw": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `keyword` analyzer helped me:

```
first_name: {
     type: "text",
     analyzer: "keyword"
}
```

[Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html#_example_output_5)

Answer (score 1):

The Difference in ASCII value cause difference in upper and lowercase start.So one solution (trick) is just save the same data which you wanted to sort in lowercase in some other field name.And use that field for sort.

This is not the perfect way, but while sorting data for drop down menus. this will help.