# How to alphabetically sort a name field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have the following definition for the name field:

```
"name": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
},
```

How do I sort this alphabetically ?

I am trying the following

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Shoes"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "keyword": {
       "order": "asc"
    }  
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": []
}
```

But the sort somehow doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

I have referred to these threads but they doesn't seem to help in my case.

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195653/elastic-search-alphabetical-sorting-based-on-first-character)

[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382734/fields-not-getting-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-in-elasticsearch/33387493)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the `name.keyword` subfield and also you have two different `sort` sections in your search, remove the empty one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Shoes"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "name.keyword": {         <---- change this
       "order": "asc"
    }  
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": []                  <---- remove this
}
```

Comment: sorry did't get the `refer to the name.keyword subfield ` part , can you explain. thanks for the help.

Comment: In your mapping, the `name` field of type `text` is the field on which you can search, but the `name.keyword` sub-field of type `keyword` is the one to use for sorting (and aggregating)